# Python library or algorithm to generate arc geometry from three coordinate pairs?

Tags: python, geometry, geodjango, django

I'm trying to write code to generate fixtures for a django/geodjango project. I need to generate geometry for arcs (line string) given three lat/long pairs; start of arc, end of arc and centre of arc. I read through the geodjango documentation but this functionality doesn't seem to be available. Does anyone know if there is a Python library that provides this functionality? Or does anyone have an algorithm I can port to python? Thanks

Comment: what kind of arc: a LineString, a curve ?

Comment: Oh sorry, a line string.

Comment: If you're underlying database is postgis, it supports curves, IE ST_GeomFromText('CIRCULARSTRING(220268 150415,220227 150505,220227 150406) from http://postgis.net/docs/ST_CurveToLine.html

Comment: Thanks. I was originally using a plpgsql function that generates an arc from the three coordinate pairs. Unfortunately, we are re-designing our installer, which means the data is now written to json files instead of being loaded straight into PostGIS/PostgreSQL. So I can't use the function anymore and I have to generate the arg geometry using Python.

Answer (score 0):

[Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) [PyQGIS](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/),  and  GeoDjango use the same API based on the [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) library:

#### With Shapely:

with a list of points:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, mapping
pt1 = Point(0,0)
pt2 = Point(20,20)
pt3 = Point (50,50)
line = LineString([pt1,pt2,pt3])
#GeoJSON format
print mapping(line)
{'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': ((0.0, 0.0), (20.0, 20.0), (50.0, 50.0))}
```

or with a list of coordinates:

```
line = LineString([(0, 0), (20,20),(50,50)])
#GeoJSON format
print mapping(line)
{'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': ((0.0, 0.0), (20.0, 20.0), (50.0, 50.0))}
```

#### with PyQGIS:

with a list of points:

```
line = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(0,0),QgsPoint(20,20),QgsPoint(50,50)])
#GeoJSON format
print line.exportToGeoJSON()
{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [0, 0], [20, 20], [50, 50] ] }
```

#### with GeoDjango (look at [Django: GEOS API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/))

with a list of coordinates:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import LineString
line = LineString((0, 0), (20, 20), (50, 50))
# GeoJSON format
print line.json
{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 20.0, 20.0 ], [ 50.0, 50.0 ] ] }
```

The resulting line is made up of two segments: (0,0) to (20,20) and (20,20) to (50,50)

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't give me an arc, it only gives me a line between three points.

Comment: ""Oh sorry, a line string" -> what is an arc ? a segment of a LineString ?

Comment: I found this image after a quick search that hopefully shows what I'm after. I may be using the wrong terminology so I apologise if I'm confusing people. Refer to item "2" in this image: http://docs.autodesk.com/CIV3D/2013/ENU/images/GUID-4B5CB65D-AC29-432D-8A64-CC409B1A9B66-low.gif. The arc is comprised of multiple line segments.

Comment: In item 2, its is a polyline with three segments (look above)

Comment: two segments, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Building on @gene 's answer above if you're looking to approximate a curve as a sequence of points using spline interpolation. In Python you can do this through the [`scipy.interpolate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) library. Particularly [1d interpolation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#d-interpolation-interp1d).

For example

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

coords = np.array([[0, 0], [25, 10], [50, 50]])

#The curve fits as a quadratic equation on three points
f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1], kind='quadratic')

#New points will be evenly distributed along x
new_x = np.linspace(np.min(coords[:, 0]), np.max(coords[:, 0]), 10)
new_y = f(new_x)

new_coords = np.vstack([new_x, new_y]).T
```

[image]

With a bit more work (play with `shapely.interpolate`) you can get a curve in segments of equal like so:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, mapping

fine_x = np.linspace(np.min(coords[:, 0]), np.max(coords[:, 0]), 1000)
fine_y = f(fine_x)

fine_coords = zip(fine_x, fine_y)
fine_line = LineString(fine_coords)

even_line = LineString([
    np.array(fine_line.interpolate(i))
    for i in np.arange(0, fine_line.length, 5) #points 5 units apart
])
```

[image]

Comment: you can simplify: `fine_coords = zip(fine_x, fine_y)`

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking to generate segments using three coordinates; start of arc, end of arc and centre of arc.

Comment: @Stodge In which case take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11332375/379566) on Stack Overflow - it should have exactly what you're after

Comment: The result is not a LineString with three points. Otherwise   you can also use all the interpolation algorithms.

Comment: @gene Yeah. I'm now thinking Stodge is after a circular arc as generalised to a line string. After looking at it a couple of times, in the picture supplied in the comment to your solution I think the centre point of the arc is the green circle to the left of the "2"

Comment: You want to compute the midpoint of the arc ? (look at [How to find the middle point of a line in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58079/how-to-find-the-middle-point-of-a-line-in-qgis/58123#58123), it is similar with shapely)

Comment: @om_henners - yes, that's what I'm after. I humbly apologise if my question and comments are confusing.

Comment: @Stodge Not a problem at all. I'd suggest adding your code as a solution with a link to the Stack Overflow answer and marking it as correct so other users can easily find the answer in the future.