# Dividing a trapezium into quarters with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon

Using QGIS 2.18.3, I need to divide a trapezium ([Math is Fun](http://www.mathsisfun.com/quadrilaterals.html) says that this is called a trapezoid in the UK - in any event, a 4-sided polygon with no sides parallel) into 4 polygons.  Please refer to my crude MS Paint approximation to visualize what I need.  I suspect that this would be accomplished by finding the midpoint along each input side and connecting it with the midpoint of the opposite side, thereby creating quarters.

Purpose: I have polygonal vector data of surveyed USA land at the section (square mile) level where each polygon is usually square, but often containing trapezium-shaped sections, that I need to divide into approximate quarter-sections.  Since square polygons would exist in the data, the ability to subdivide a square would thus also be a requirement.

The ability to accomplish this subdivision with multiple sections at one time would be a bonus.

A search through the plugins didn't turn up anything, nor did a Google search.  Sadly, I have no programming skills to accomplish this.  Suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will rely my answer on [gene's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58123/63384) creative answer, and I will proceed from there.

You need to do the following steps:

1. Convert the polygon shapefile into polyline shapefile using `Vector -> Geometry tool -> polygon to polyline`

[image]

[image]

2. Make the polyline layer in the table of content the active layer

[image]

3. Select the polylines (4 boundary lines)

[image]

4. Copy and paste the following code into python editor and run it. It will creates a mid point at each line:

   ```
   def mid(pt1, pt2):
     x = (pt1.x() + pt2.x())/2
     y = (pt1.y() + pt2.y())/2
     return QgsPoint(x,y)

   def pair(list):
   #Iterate over pairs in a list
       for i in range(1, len(list)):
           yield list[i-1], list[i]

   def create_geometry(point,pr):
       # create geometry record 
       seg = QgsFeature()
       seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point))
       pr.addFeatures( [seg] )

   # memory layer
   pt_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "midpoint", "memory")
   pr = pt_layer.dataProvider()

   mylayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer() # This line was missing in the original code 
   for elem in mylayer.selectedFeatures():
       line = elem.geometry()
       for seg_start, seg_end in pair(line.asPolyline()):
          line_start = QgsPoint(seg_start)
          line_end = QgsPoint(seg_end)
          # midpoint 
          midpt= mid(line_start, line_end)
          # add midpoint point to layer
          create_geometry(midpt,pr)
          pt_layer.updateExtents()

   QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([pt_layer])
   ```

[image]

5. Go to `settings -> Snapping Options -> Snapping Option: select Advanced`

[image]

6. Select the polygon layer in the table of content
7. Start editing the polygon shapefile
8. Select Split feature [image]
9. Cut the polygon using the mid point as snapping feature, and save the edits.

[image]

[image]

[image]