# Pointing the center of polygon

Tags: qgis

So my question is about giving the middle point of a polygon based on lines inside the polygon

the picture will explain everything

The blue line is the distance between first and last line in my polygon which is ( 246m ) so i need to get the middle point of these lines which is ( 123m ) so i need to get point in this distance

also you can see in the picture that i have a lot of polygons each polygon have ( line at the beginning and line at the end )

[image]

Comment: It is not clear how you have derived the "blue line".  If you just want the mid-point of the line then there are ways to do this- see, for exampled, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58079/finding-middle-point-midpoint-of-line-in-qgis
which covers the expression $length / 2.0

Comment: the "blue line " it's just explain about where i need to calculate from the first line inside the polygon to the last line inside the polygon

Comment: What does the blue line represent?

Comment: its represent to where i want to start and end my distance

Comment: As you say, you have a lot of polygons and I cannot see which one you are referring to. Perhaps it would help if you modify the picture to highlight which polyon you are talking about.