# Making middle point going on curve lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, point-creation

I've these lines so when i want to point the middle by going to `Vector > Geometry Tools > Centroid` the point goes on the Straight line only, but when i have lines with curves the point doesn't goes with the line as you can see in the image.

How can i make the middle point going on the curve lines?

[image]

Comment: Lots of options https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58079/finding-middle-point-midpoint-of-line-in-qgis

Comment: No i still need help

Comment: Can you provide a geometry WKT (and the coordinate system) of one curved line where the centroid doesn't fit in the middle line ? Maybe try to generate geometry from expression with `line_interpolate_point($geometry, length($geometry) / 2)` https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?#line-interpolate-point

Comment: how can i provide it ?

Comment: Are you trying to find the point that divides each line segment into two equal length parts?

Comment: @Spacedman exactly

Comment: wkt_geom id length_m
LineString (14.4355352909697352 27.02017888747414531, 14.43499962884913757 27.02049135606148411, 14.43467536561014164 27.02009050742625007, 14.43510964655483875 27.0198349007725902, 14.43485023517483512 27.01944410804897956) 0 235

Answer (score 4):

Use the ["Interpolate point on line"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#interpolate-point-on-line) tool from the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

[image]

Choose your line layer, and then find "Edit" in the dropdown for Distance:

[image]

Enter `$length / 2` as the expression.

[image]

Halfway-points appear:

[image]

Comment: After clicking run no point shows in the lines idk why !!

Comment: i don't know why there is no dot's only the new layer shows after clicking on run any solution ?

Comment: Is it creating a new layer?

Comment: yes but without points

Comment: any help !!!!!!

Comment: @AbdullahMuthanna can you supply sample data? Edit your question with a link